# Pass by value for recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, pass-by-value

I am trying to pass a parameter "by value". I have tried making a deep copy of the parameter that is passed recursively in order to prevent any changes from circling back to the parent function calls.

Here is a snippet of code that tries to generate the array of all possible parentheses.

```
def generateParenthesis(n):
    #Iterate for each move.
    M = 2 * n
    retArray = []
    def recHelper(numMoves, perm, stack):
        print("Function call: ", numMoves, perm, stack)
        newPerm = copy.deepcopy(perm)
        newStack = stack.copy()
        #Base case, no moves
        if (numMoves == 0):
            retArray.append(newPerm)
            return

        #Case when left move is valid
        if (numMoves != len(newStack)):
            #Apply the left move. Pass it recursively
            newPerm +='('
            #Update the stack accordingly
            newStack.append('(')
            #Decrease numMoves
            newNumMoves = numMoves - 1
            #Call it recursively
            recHelper(newNumMoves, newPerm, newStack)
        #Case when right move is valid
        if len(newStack) != 0:
            #Apply the right move. Pass it recursively
            newPerm +=')'
            #Update the stack accordingly, delete the top, last elm
            newStack.pop()
            #Decrease numMoves
            newNumMoves = numMoves - 1
            #Call it recursively
            recHelper(newNumMoves, newPerm, newStack)
        #done
        return
    recHelper(M, "", [])
    return retArray
```

Unfortunately, calling `generateParenthesis(1)` returns `['()','()(', '()()']` and not `['()']`.

Comment: is the outcome to pass an int to generateParenthesis and have a list of '()' in your list equal to you passed param value?

Because this is a very odd way of doing it if that's the only required outcome.
My assumption this is related to a test to demonstrate your understanding of recursion.

Comment: The `perm` parameter is a string, which are immutable, so making a copy should be necessary (although harmless other than wasting execution time).

Comment: I don't think your recursive function does what you think it does. Can you tell us what the result of `generateParenthesis(2)` and `generateParenthesis(3)` should be?

Comment: @Reti43 the result of generateParenthesis(2) should be: ['()()', '(())'], which are the only valid permutations of parenthesis including two pairs of left and right

Comment: @Justin what are your thoughts oh the solution ?

Comment: @Niloct I think the solution seems right! I was wondering less about a solution to this problem (it's on leetcode so there are solutions public) but I am wondering more about why my code doesn't work. It might be a conceptual misunderstanding on my behalf

Comment: If you put `print('first', newNumMoves, newStack)` in the first if block and another one similarly in the second, you should be able to follow what your code does and why.

Comment: @Justin see updated answer.

Comment: @Justin are you there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def generateParenthesis(n):
    retArray = []

    def append_solutions(partial, opened_p, closed_p):
        if opened_p < n:
            append_solutions(partial + '(', opened_p + 1, closed_p)
        if closed_p < n and opened_p > closed_p:
            append_solutions(partial + ')', opened_p, closed_p + 1)

        if opened_p == closed_p == n and partial:
            retArray.append(partial)

    append_solutions('', 0, 0)
    return retArray

print(generateParenthesis(1))
print(generateParenthesis(2))
print(generateParenthesis(3))
print(generateParenthesis(4))
print(generateParenthesis(5))
```

After 3 hours of simplifying ideas, I came with this working code.

Now it finds things like `(()())()` for `generateParenthesis(4)`, for instance.

The code is very self explanatory. You keep a count of opened/closed parenthesis and only close parenthesis when there are correspondent opened.

I chose not to use a stack because since everything in Python is passed by "pointer copy", stacks (i.e. lists in your OP) would require a costly `list(stack)` in the function body, creating a local copy of the list.

Notice that I create new strings (`partial + '('`, for instance), and these new string objects are passed by "pointer copy" to recursion calls.

(Sorry I lack a better term now. But this is important)

---

**Edit**

Your solution has a problem with the variable `newPerm`. Its value is leaking into the second recursive function. Also, you need to understand that all your copying of values is not needed except for the stack.

See how your function can be simplified. I think it's working:

```
def generateParenthesisOP(n):
    #Iterate for each move.
    M = 2 * n
    retArray = []
    def recHelper(numMoves, perm, stack):
        print("Function call: ", numMoves, perm, stack)
        if numMoves == 0:
            retArray.append(perm)
            return

        if numMoves != len(stack):
            left_stack = list(stack)
            left_stack.append('(')
            recHelper(numMoves - 1, perm + '(', left_stack)
        if len(stack) != 0:
            right_stack = list(stack)
            right_stack.pop()
            recHelper(numMoves - 1, perm + ')', right_stack)
    recHelper(M, "", [])
    return retArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` operator to add to a list rather than `.append()` behavior to best emulate pass by value behavior.

Python officially abides by pass-by-object-reference. In your case, when a list `stack` or `perm` passed and modified in the child function, the parent function's `stack` or `perm` will see the updated variable.